# Why does my add like method return "cannot read property of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a method to handle adding a "like" on click. It's supposed to toggle isLiked to the opposite of the previous state and increment likes count by 1.

I think the error might be due to conflicting states but I'm not sure how to verify this.

```
addLike = postId => {
    this.setState({
        posts: this.state.posts.map(post => {
            if (post.id === postId) {
                return {
                    ...post,
                    likes: post.likes + 1,
                    isLiked: !post.isLiked
                };
            }
            return {
                post
            };
        })
    });
};
```

I was expecting like to increment by 1 and isLiked to be set to true. However, on click I'm getting an error that it "cannot read property of undefined".

Comment: On which object/line are you getting the error?

Comment: I'm getting the error on my posts object when clicking on the icon

Answer (score 1):

You can code defensively against potentially missing properties:

```
if (post && post.id === postId) { // is it possible your posts array has `undefined` or `null` entry in it?
   return {
      ...post,
      likes: post.likes + 1; 
      isLiked: !post.isLiked
   };
...
```

And elsewhere, where trying to access a property on a `null` or `undefined` object could throw that exception. For example, is `state.posts` properly populate or at least initialized to an empty array `[]`? If not, `this.state.posts.map` could also throw the same error.

Furthermore, use [React DevTools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) to inspect your state and check the values.

Comment: While this is true, I don't think there's enough evidence in the question to say that this is the answer. The error above would indicate that post *itself* is undefined, as opposed to `post.likes` being empty.

Comment: Posts is properly initialized to an array of objects. Other methods such as addComment and InputChangeHandler function as intended with current state.

Comment: @Hyetigran Interesting. Did you try the React DevTools Chrome extension that I've linked as well? It's a good tool to observe the component tree, props, state, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your `setState` should rely on the previous state, then better go with the syntax with updater function. Something like

```
   this.setState(({posts, ...restOfTheState}) => 
      ({ 
         posts: posts.map( // mapping logic here
         ...restOfTheState,
      });
```

BTW, `state.posts` *was* initialized, right?